# Apache camel multiple file processing with exec

Tags: apache-camel

I am having trouble fixing this simple route, getting exception right after execute. Seems like execute is acting as Producer and over writing file.

Exception:

> org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot store file: C:\camel_tests\stage\Downloads.rar

Route:

Home directory will have a rar file with images, that should be extracted with winrar.exe, each file in the rar is file processed, and eventually moved to arch directory once this route done. Last successful stage is extracting files in the stage directory.

Here `CMD_EXPLODE` = `"\"C:/Program Files/WinRAR/WinRAR.exe\"";`

```
from("file://C:/camel_tests/home?fileName=Downloads.rar&preMove=//C:/camel_tests/stage")
.to("exec:"+Consts.CMD_EXPLODE+"?args=e Downloads.rar&workingDir=C:/camel_tests/stage&outFile=decompress_output.txt")
.to("file://C:/camel_tests/stage?exclude=.*.rar")
.process(new PrintFiles())
.to("file://C:/camel_tests/stage?fileName=Downloads.rar&move=//C:/camel_tests/arch").end();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should split that into 2 routes. The first that does the from -> exec
And a 2nd from -> process -> to

The 2nd will then process each of the extracted file from winrar.

Comment: Thank you, when i break them to three parts, it works. But i would like to pass along correlation id (stage1 to stage3) and some other header details, so that i can use aggregator 
at the end for combining/processing. So when i connect them using "direct" or "seda", getting same exception as before.